# UDP Daemon Class: The attempted operation is not supported for the type of Object Referenced

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm creating a UDP Daemon class in C#, after setting the breakpoint in Visual Studio I see "The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced." within `this::ip::Address::ScopeId::base`. The ScopeId throws exception `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException`. The error code is 10045 / OperationNotSupported.

Calling Code:

```
namespace Foo.Tester
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var TestDaemon = new UDPDaemon();
            TestDaemon.port = 9999;
            TestDaemon.Start();
            ...
```

UDPDaemon Class:

```
{
    public class UDPDaemon
    {

        public int receivedDataLength; 
        public byte[] data; 
        public IPEndPoint ip; 
        public Socket socket; 
        public IPEndPoint sender;
        public EndPoint Remote; 
        public string raw;
        public int port { get; set; }
        public LogRow row;


        public UDPDaemon() 
        {
            ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
            socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            Remote = (EndPoint)(sender);
        }
        public void Start()
        {
            socket.Bind(ip);
            while (true)
            {
                data = new byte[1024];
                receivedDataLength = socket.ReceiveFrom(data, ref Remote);
                raw = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, receivedDataLength);
                row = new LogRow(raw);
                //Will eventually move to Queue, but just print it for now
                Console.WriteLine(row.ClientIp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. What is causing this exception and what does the exception mean?
2. How come I only see the exception if I set a breakpoint in VS?
3. I have just started learning this language, so if anything else seems off in the code that would be good to know.

Comment: The port isn't being set in `ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);` and that is causing the Socket Exceptions , so this is some sort of basic C# OO concept I am missing ...

Comment: Ah, I see now, ip is assigned during the construction of the instance of the object, and the port isn't assigned until after that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to use port inside the constructor, you need to pass it as a constructor argument, not to set it later, e.g.:

```
public class UDPDaemon
{
    public int receivedDataLength; 
    public byte[] data; 
    public IPEndPoint ip; 
    public Socket socket; 
    public IPEndPoint sender;
    public EndPoint Remote; 
    public string raw;
    public int Port { get; private set; }
    public LogRow row;

    public UDPDaemon(int port) 
    {
        Port = port;
        ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
        socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        Remote = (EndPoint)(sender);
    }
 ....
```